# Making multiple connection to different mysql server installed in same machine

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed two apache and mysql server in my ubuntu 10.04. One is in /opt/lampp ( localhost:8080) and another is in /var/www ( localhost ). Port configuration I have done successfully its running smoothly now. I have some projects in both servers.

Now I want to connect DB from localhost:8080 to localhost. That is, I have a project on /opt/lampp/htdocs/connection_test/ ( localhost:8080 ) . I need to connect DB on localhost . Is it possible ? If yes how ?. Is there any other ways to handle this ?

Comment: If you have two instances of MySQL running on your computer (which is rather silly, but possible), they should (in fact, they must) be listening in different ports. So you'd just have to check which port is which, and enter the right port when entering the address to connect to.

Comment: can you give me a example ?

Comment: Of what? Checking the ports is part of the Apache/MySQL configuration (which I really don't have a copy at hand to show you). Passing the correct port to the connection function in PHP is just a parameter -- most people leave it out, and it defaults to 3306 (the default port); but you can just enter a value there for a different port. Look up the documentation of whatever function (mysql, mysqli, whatever) you're using to connect.